# Non-generic object of generic type

Tags: java, generics

For following codes:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add(45);
```

And

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList();
ar.add(45);
```

I am getting compile time error at line `ar.add(45)` as:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(int)
location: class java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
                al.add(45);
                  ^
```

Both piece of code is failing for invalid input . Then why compiler is raising warning of unchecked or unsafe operation for second piece of code?

Comment: Use an IDE for Java development. Don't try it from the command line if you have little experience with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then why compiler is raising warning of unchecked or unsafe operation for second piece of code?

Because you're assigning an `ArrayList` to a variable with type `ArrayList<String>`. That means that while the compiler will enforce the expectation that the array list will only contain strings when you reference that list through `ar`, it can't be sure that you don't have *other* references to the non-parameterized `ArrayList` that you'll use to add non-strings to it, like this:

```
ArrayList anythingGoes = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> onlyStrings = anythingGoes; // Unchecked/unsafe op
anythingGoes.add(new Date());
for (String s : onlyStrings) { // Blows up
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It means there is no harm in writing `ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList();` ?

Comment: @Mac: No, it means there **is** harm in writing that statement. That's why you're getting the warning.

Comment: Ahh It means that compiler is warning that in future such situation might occur where we might be traping into `ClassCastException`..right?

Comment: @Mac: Yes, that's basically it.

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second code you do not specify the type parameter of the ArrayList. You could write it in Java 7 as:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* distinct issues here.

Firstly -

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList();
```

You're telling the compiler that `ar` is a list of strings, but you're assigning it to a list of *raw* types (i.e. unbounded). Hence the compiler will warn you of an unchecked or unsafe operation. You should use something like either option below:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
```

(the second option is a Java 7 example and simply reduces the amount of typing you have to do. The result is the same).

Secondly -

```
ar.add(45);
```

You're adding an integer (45) into a list of strings. The compiler won't allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your generic data type as Integer

if you want to add integers